# How to make Finder remember its window size and column sizes?

Tags: macos, finder, font, window-manager, split-view

OS X remember the Size of the Finder window and the size of the columns in Cover flow (or any other) view.

It seems like something very basic that should just be there. But instead, I have to continuously resize columns to see filenames and resize the window so I can see a reasonable amount of stuff.

I know there are script that can allow you to achieve this *manually*, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Only Apple would be able to answer 'why?'

Comment: I did. I totally forgot to ask the most important part, "How?" because I became so frustrated by the fact that they don't seem to care much for the little - but important - details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest answer to 'how' rather than 'why' is:

Opt[alt] drag a column sizer. That size becomes the new default, after you relaunch Finder. Only works for column view, not coverflow.

Other options, though each is temporary

- Double click a column sizer to set that column to show full content width.
- Right-click a column sizer for more options.

To relaunch Finder, hold Opt and right-click Finder in the dock. Relaunch will be in the context menu.

Comment: I also use OPT-Resize (with the mouse) to have all columns fitting in the window. For the full filenames I have the "View path bar" enabled and selecting a file it shows the full filenames on the bottom.What I can;t stand is that the OPT-Resize option doesn't stick.

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata OPT+doubleclick does not "save" for the next time, but OPT+drag does "save", and the next time you open the column will be that size.

Comment: @JosephHansen I probably didn't express myself well. I want to resize the Finder windows in a way that they don't show the horizontal scrollbar. So I OPT-drag the right side. It resize them with all columns fitting, but after a while it's always all over again. In other words I'd like an "auto-fitting" option, I hate the horizontal scrollbars in Finder

Comment: For Mac OS 10.14 Mojave, OPT+drag sets all columns to be the same size.